# Regex whitespace

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_match('/<div class="prices">/s<h3>(.+?)<\/h3>/is', $response, $matches);
```

There's whitespace and potentially new lines between the prices div and the h3 tag.  How do I use /s to match that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't use `/s`, you use `\s*`.

- It's a backslash (`\`), not a slash (`/`).
- The `*` afterwards means that it matches *zero or more* whitespace characters.

Also, please consider using an HTML parser if you are trying to find HTML tags. A proper HTML parser will be able to correctly handle whitespace, HTML comments and other features of HTML that your regular expression cannot handle.